# How to add own custom IME at Select Input method dialog

Tags: android, ime, android-input-method

I'd like to show my own IME in the Select input method chooser dialog like the Japanese IME and the Chinese IME. How can I do that?

I am new to Android. I have tested Greek IME and other IME. Although `.apk` is successfully uploaded. But can't show in it and how to choose own IME from this place.

What do I need to do in my code?

Comment: Have you read this: <http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/creating-input-method.html>

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to activate the installed keyboards before you can select them in the Input Method menu. For this you need to open Settings -> Language & Keyboard and in this menu check the keyboards you would like to use. This probably should get your GreekIME running.

Now for coding your own soft keyboard, there is an example which is delivered with the Android SDK. You can find it in `<Andoid SDK Base>/samples/SoftKeyboard`. The process is a bit poorly documented, but when you get the example up and running you can start to tweak the example a bit and you should get the hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

Nice writeup about
[Onscreen Input Methods](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html) from developer.android.com

In part ...
**What is an input method?**

The Android IMF is designed to support a variety of IMEs, including soft keyboard, hand-writing recognizers, and hard keyboard translators. Our focus, however, will be on **soft keyboards**, since this is the kind of input method that is currently part of the platform.